# Is there any way to run an older version of the Steam client?

Tags: steam, technical-issues, macos

The latest auto-update of Steam (5 November 2015) has broken the Steam client on OS X 10.6.8.  This means I can no longer install or update any of my games, nor even play games that use the Steam DRM system.

Is there any way to install an older version of the steam client, and prevent it from auto-updating itself to the latest, broken, version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Paul's advice to get an old version (non-pirated).  Personally, I got the last working version off my backup drive.  Then I googled for advice on blocking updates.  It's actually quite easy.

Make a text file containing 1 line:
BootStrapperInhibitAll=Enable

Name it Steam.cfg.  Open the Steam app with right-click -> Show Package Contents.  Put your Steam.cfg file inside Contents/MacOS within the app.  Now it won't auto-update.

Comment: Regarding downloading from sites other than Valve, MacUpdate.com is an entirely reputable site.  It still has the version from 25 Feb 2014.  Other reputable sites also have older version.

I'm not sure why somebody downvoted without comment.  My method is working for me.  It's possible that it only works from a backup instead of a new install, but I can't test that.

Comment: Hmm.  It looks like the "installers" you can download only install a 5MB app that downloads the real app (600+MB)… which will of course download the newest version.  So you really do need a backed up version from an install.

Comment: But the good news is that if you do have a backed-up version your instructions work perfectly!

Answer (score 2):

Yes. **But it's not really recommended.**

There are sites out there like FileHippo or OldVersion.com that will let you download the older versions of the Steam client. However, it's REALLY not recommended to do so.

With that being said, unless you want to block Steam from checking its servers for a new update, this will almost always involve the usage of a pirated Steam client.

> Usage of a pirated Steam client is against the Steam user agreement and cause problems for you as the user, the least of which is the permanent banning of your Steam Account as well as being banned from any games which uses the Steam VAC.

If your OSX Client isn't working, before using an older version, try heading to the Steam community forum and see if there are others with the same issue. If possible, reinstall the client. (You SHOULD be able to do this without having to redownload the games already installed.)

Comment: I have already installed an older version of the Steam client - but it immediately updated itself to the most recent version, which no longer runs on 10.6.8.  Is there a way to block the Steam client from updating _itself_ without blocking it from updating / installing games?

Comment: Without blocking it, no. Steam's client ALWAYS auto-updates when online and will update when you shut down and restart.

Comment: Downloading the steam client from anywhere else but Steam is asking for trouble. You could just give up your username and password on reddit, that is about the same. I highly recommend **NOT** doing that.

Comment: @BulletByMods that's the same that I said... I'm not recommending this but if they want to know, there it is. Unless they want to keep it offline. And using an older version doesn't mean that it's unsecure as far as its transmission protocols are concerned for user and pass.